# Response.Redirect calling string causing Input string was not in a correct format error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following C#

```
protected void sprint_availability_ItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string sprintid = "";
        Label lbl = (sprint_availability.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("sprint_id_lbl")) as Label;
        if (lbl != null)
            sprintid = lbl.Text;

        string projectid = "";
        Label pid = (sprint_availability.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("project_id_lbl")) as Label;
        if (pid != null)
            projectid = pid.Text;

        string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

        String query = "DELETE FROM sprints WHERE [sprint_id]  = '" + sprintid + "'";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConnection.Close();

        Response.Redirect("project.aspx?project_id="+ pid);
    }
```

The SQL Query works fine as it is deleting the row without any issue, however the redirect is redirecting to `http://project.aspx?project_id=System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label`

This is the section of the asp code which displays the label I am trying to call

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("project_id") %>' runat="server" ID="project_id_lbl" Visible="false"/><br />
```

Comment: `pid` is a `Label`, you probably want `projectid` instead: `Response.Redirect("project.aspx?project_id="+ projectid);`

Comment: You should use `project_id="+ pid.Text);` or `project_id="+ projectid);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pid is a `Label`, adding it to a string like you do in the redirect call invokes the class method ToString() and in case of a Label this method prints out the class name.

You need to use

```
Response.Redirect("project.aspx?project_id="+ pid.Text);
```

However, in your code there is a potential bug that need to be fixed as soon as possible. Do not use string concatenation to build sql queries. Use a parameterized query

```
    string query = "DELETE FROM sprints WHERE [sprint_id]  = @id";
   string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using(SqlCommand myCommand(query, myConnection))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarWChar).Value = sprintid;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

String concatenation leads to Sql Injections and to parsing problem. Albeit. in your case, this seems to be improbable it is better to use this approach everytime to avoid any pitfalls. Also enclosing the disposable objects like the connection and the command in a using statement ensures a proper closing and disposing of these objects

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. Also, thank you for the heads up. I'm new to all things programming and databases so this is very useful to know